# JQuery Validation Plugin - form submits on first attempt; then never submits again

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

This has to be simple but my JS experience is thin at best.

I've got a few fields on a shopping cart that are required. When the form is submitted the first time, it correctly identifies invalid fields but submits the form anyway. If I back click and do it again, it prevents me from checking out even if the fields are correctly populated.

Having looked at other posts, I know it's not attaching on page load/prior to submit.

Form fields:
1 select box with us state options is required
2 radio buttons for residential or business, selecting one of them is required

Simple JS from tutorials:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(){
    $("#cart").validate({
        rules: {
            "attributes[foodbank]" : "required",
            "attributes[share_info]" : "required",
            "attributes[delivery]" : "required"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code, like what is in the `validate()` function?

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Scumbag form - submits on first attempt, then never submits again. (Sorry.)

Comment: the validate function is whatever is in the JQuery Validate plugin

Comment: added the select box tag and the radio buttons.